# How to call multiple elements of same class using getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, loops, getelementsbyclassname

This is frustrating.

I am currently doing a practice and I'd like to add a class and remove another class on a div with the class "sap". I have 3 divs with the same class and I intend to use a loop to get all elements with the same class but it doesn't seem to be working and I don't know  why.

I am using only vanilla JS.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks for any help rendered.

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="boot()">show</button>
<div class=panel>
<div id="container" class="sap">
  <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
<div class="smooth">
</div>
</div>
<div class="sap">
  <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
<div class="smooth">
</div>
</div>
<div class="sap">
  <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
<div class="smooth">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function boot(){
  for(var i=0;i<=3;i++){
      var box=document.getElementsByClassName("sap");
    if(box[i].classList.contains("content")){
       box[i].classList.add("flush");
       }}
  }
```

Comment: "_add a class and remove another class on a div_"  Your code does not have any logic to remove a class as you have mentioned? Please elaborate in details what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: i hv different css styling attached to each class respectively

Comment: But what is the exact issue you are having here? and also add the minimal css to code also.

Comment: You are not removing the `sap` class in your code, even though you've stated it's your intention to, in the question description

Answer (score 1):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

You can use the more modern `document.querySelectorAll`, spread its (array like) result into an `Array` and perform the wanted action on that. Or, even shorter, select all `.sap > .content` in one go and perfom the action. Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", boot);

function boot(evt) {
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  // just for this demo snippet
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".flush, .flushAlt")]
    .forEach(elem => 
      elem.classList.remove("flush","flushAlt"));
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  if (evt.target.dataset.action === "boot") {
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".sap")] // all div.sap
      .forEach(elem =>
        [...elem.querySelectorAll(".content")] // all div.content *within* div.sap
          .forEach(content => 
            content.classList.add("flush")))
  } else if (evt.target.dataset.action === "bootAlt") {
    // all div.content *within* div.sap in one go
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".sap > .content")]
      .forEach(content => 
            content.classList.add("flushAlt"))
  }
}
```

```css
.flush {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flushAlt {
  color: white;
  background-color: brown;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button data-action="boot">show</button>
<button data-action="bootAlt">show (alternative)</button>
<div class=panel>
  <div id="container" class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this `var box=document.getElementsByClassName("sap");` outside the loop. This will give the collection of the html elements with this class `sap`. Then you will like to iterate this collection , so you need not to hard code the number 3. Note in you code you did `<=3`. It will be `<` but not `<=`. Since `<=` the index starts from 0, so `<=` will also try to match 4th element which is not there.

Then get the first child of the `div.sap` using `children`

```js
function boot() {
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName("sap");
  for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    const firstChild = box[i].children[0]
    if (firstChild.classList.contains("content")) {
      firstChild.classList.add("flush");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.sap {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  color: green;
}

.flush {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="boot()">show</button>
<div class=panel>
  <div id="container" class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works, except there is no div with class `content` and `sap` at the same time so when you run the snippet below you won't see any changes (no class will be added to any element):

```js
function boot() {
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName("sap");
  for(var i=0; i < box.length; i++) {
    if(box[i].classList.contains("content")) {
       box[i].classList.add("flush");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.flush {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #09f;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="boot()">show</button>
<div class=panel>
  <div id="container" class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
  <div class="smooth">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case you wanted to add the class to an element of class `sap` that has a child element with class `content`:

```js
function boot() {
  var box = document.getElementsByClassName("sap");
  for(var i=0; i < box.length; i++) {
    if(box[i].querySelector('.content') !== null) {
      box[i].classList.add("flush");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.flush {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #09f;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="boot()">show</button>
<div class=panel>
  <div id="container" class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
    <div class="smooth"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sap">
    <div class="content"><span>unveil</span></div>
  <div class="smooth">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```